# how to center text using html and css

Tags: html, css, center

I have got some text on my html site using a div tag so I can center the text but it wont center.

This is what I put in the HTML

```
<div id="info"> 
Welcome
</div>
```

This is what I put in the CSS

```
#info {
color: #0F0;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
}
```

I have used the right css code to center the text but for some reason it wont center. Has anybody got any ideas?

Comment: It does center. I copied your code in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22eu6ge7/) and the Welcome appears in the center.

Comment: it is in the center..

Comment: This might be a part of code and some other class may be overlapping it

Answer (score 4):

`text-align: center;` is correct. Your code should work as expected.
Try to validate your site and see if you did any typos or so: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ive managed to sort it now but have you got any idea on how to space the text out so theres like 20% width before the text and 20% width after the text?

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine https://codeide.co/master/LpcINKJK. I think you should check element's width.

```
#info {
    color: #0F0;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align: center;
```

For more details read this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP

Answer (score -1):

Center-align text in an HTML page: Hello

```html
<center>Hello</center>
```